# Javascript get last visited page url

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the url of the last visited page. The reason is just to know the last product that the user visited. I am writting code in Javascript an I have tried

```
var x = document.referrer;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

and also this

```
var currentLocation = window.history.previous.href;
```

but with no result. Please in case there is a working solution, I would be happy to know.

Comment: document.referrer doesn't work unless the current page was navigated to via a link from the previous page, as per MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `document.referrer` instead of `window.history.previous.href;`

Change your code as,

```
var currentLocation = document.referrer;
```

Hope this helps!